# What will be a good UI design for the iPhone app wise notification

Tags: iphone, notification, guidance

I have a background thread working on collecting data, once that's ready, I want to send out a global notification such that all the views can get it. That's easily achievable logically. But visually, I want the user, while on any view of the app, got notified as well so he can prompted to take some action - e.g., ignore or reload - once see the prompt.

Now the question is - what'll the best design for this prompt? a popup dialog definitely serves the purpose, but it's annoying of it pops up frequently; a top down notification or a bottom up notification is better - but can I do that globally? and I have a TabBar at the bottom, so the top down might be better, will overlay the navigation bar be a good idea for that purpose?

any other suggestions?

Comment: popups are annoying - users will not like that - and that's also the reason for the new iOS notifications area, why can't you use that?

Comment: I want give user option to make their decisions. Not sure the new iOS notification can do that or is it just for notification only. Do u have some doc to share?

Answer (score 1):

**iOS has a defined [UX guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)**, I would go with them.

This is what it [has to say about modals](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW24):

> Modality is most appropriate when:
>
> - It’s critical to get the user’s attention.
> - A task must be completed (or explicitly abandoned) to avoid leaving the user’s data in an ambiguous state.

If you feel your situation relates to these terms, then **a modal (an alert) is the appropiate way to go**. If it doesn't relate, then go for another option, such as the mentioned [Notification Center](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#notification).

---

On a side note, I would like to address the "popups are annoying" myth by quoting an extract of the document:

> People appreciate being able to accomplish a self-contained subtask in a modal view, because the context shift is clear and temporary.